# Mysql Full Text Search Order By Relevance Results Incorrect arguments to Match

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I need Mysql Full Text Search Implementation on my website. My intention is if user enter search term, most relevance results should come first and other results should come next.

```
SELECT pr.*
, MATCH (pr.title) AGAINST ('Samsung Galaxy S6' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance_1
, MATCH (pr.description, pr.tags) AGAINST ('Samsung Galaxy S6' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance_2
, MATCH (category.name, category.description) AGAINST ('Samsung Galaxy S6' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance_3
FROM products AS pr
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = pr.category_id
WHERE MATCH (pr.title, pr.description, pr.tags, category.name, category.description) AGAINST ('Samsung Galaxy S6' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY (relevance_1 * 3) + (relevance_2 * 2) + relevance_3 DESC
```

here is my [sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0549/9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In full text searches you need a `FULLTEXT` index in your fiddle i can see there 2 indexes one for table `products` and other one `category` for products you have a compound index on 3 columns `title, description, tags` and for category you have compound index involving 2 columns and in your select statement you are referencing one column title (aliased as relevance_1) which will result as an error

> Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

because it can't find a index for title column only so you have to specify all the columns in `MATCH()` statement on which full text index was defined , same problem with your `WHERE` clause which includes 3 columns from table products and 2 columns from category and you have defined them in a single `MATCH` statement

> MATCH (pr.title, pr.description, pr.tags, category.name,
>   category.description)

which is again wrong you have to specify 2 match statements based on your full text indexes definition, criteria of these to match statements depends on you how you want them using `AND/OR`

So final working query will be something like

```
SELECT pr.*
, MATCH (pr.title,pr.description, pr.tags) AGAINST ('Samsung Galaxy S6' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance_2
, MATCH (category.name, category.description) AGAINST ('Samsung Galaxy S6' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance_3
FROM products AS pr
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = pr.category_id
WHERE MATCH (pr.title, pr.description, pr.tags) AGAINST ('Samsung Galaxy S6' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR 
MATCH (category.name, category.description) AGAINST ('Samsung Galaxy S6' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY (relevance_2 * 2) + relevance_3 DESC
```

[`DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0549/14)